# Issue deserializing stripe json response

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have made a class to deserialize stripe json response it works find but on some i  am getting error :

```
Cannot convert null to a value type.
```

Even though i can see type is always there at the end.

This is the response:

```
  {
  "id": "evt_1Dezu4HJCcuwD0sbvkmV6bEb",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2018-11-08",
  "created": 1544252828,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "sub_E7ExxxXGawn6cu",
      "object": "subscription",
      "application_fee_percent": null,
      "billing": "charge_automatically",
      "billing_cycle_anchor": 1544252827,
      "cancel_at_period_end": false,
      "canceled_at": null,
      "created": 1544252827,
      "current_period_end": 1544339227,
      "current_period_start": 1544252827,
      "customer": "cus_E7xxxQqowY9",
      "days_until_due": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "discount": null,
      "ended_at": null,
      "items": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "si_E7EMDEdBnD6wUx",
            "object": "subscription_item",
            "created": 1544252828,
            "metadata": {
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "plan_E5lRIPvrkNuRBB",
              "object": "plan",
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 0,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1543997153,
              "currency": "usd",
              "interval": "day",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": false,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": "Free Plan",
              "product": "prod_E1CBxxxpNa5Lf02d",
              "tiers": null,
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_E7xxxXGawn6cu"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_E7xxxXGawn6cu"
      },
      "livemode": false,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "plan": {
        "id": "plan_E5lRIPxxxkNuRBB",
        "object": "plan",
        "active": true,
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "amount": 0,
        "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
        "created": 1543997153,
        "currency": "usd",
        "interval": "day",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "livemode": false,
        "metadata": {
        },
        "nickname": "Free Plan",
        "product": "prod_E1CBZpNa5Lf02d",
        "tiers": null,
        "tiers_mode": null,
        "transform_usage": null,
        "trial_period_days": null,
        "usage_type": "licensed"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "start": 1544252827,
      "status": "active",
      "tax_percent": null,
      "trial_end": null,
      "trial_start": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_OJV215KMm",
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "customer.subscription.created"
}
```

And class :

```
public class WebHookObjec
{

    public int created { get; set; }
    public bool livemode { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string @object { get; set; }
    public object request { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; } 
    public int pending_webhooks { get; set; }
    public string api_version { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }

    public class Metadata
    {
    }


    public class Plan
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public bool active { get; set; }
        public object aggregate_usage { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
        public string billing_scheme { get; set; }
        public int created { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string interval { get; set; }
        public int interval_count { get; set; }
        public bool livemode { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
        public string nickname { get; set; }
        public string product { get; set; }
        public object tiers { get; set; }
        public object tiers_mode { get; set; }
        public object transform_usage { get; set; }
        public int trial_period_days { get; set; }
        public string usage_type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Phase
    {
        public object application_fee_percent { get; set; }
        public object coupon { get; set; }
        public int end_date { get; set; }
        public List<Plan> plans { get; set; }
        public int start_date { get; set; }
        public object tax_percent { get; set; }
        public bool trial { get; set; }
        public object trial_end { get; set; }
    }
    public class PreviousAttributes
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public string billing { get; set; }
        public object canceled_at { get; set; }
        public object completed_at { get; set; }
        public int created { get; set; }
        public object current_phase { get; set; }
        public string customer { get; set; }
        public object invoice_settings { get; set; }
        public bool livemode { get; set; }
        public List<Phase> phases { get; set; }
        public object released_at { get; set; }
        public object released_subscription { get; set; }
        public string renewal_behavior { get; set; }
        public object renewal_interval { get; set; }
        public string revision { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public object subscription { get; set; }
        public Plan plan { get; set; }
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        public int start { get; set; }
        public object tax_percent { get; set; }
        public int trial_end { get; set; }
        public int trial_start { get; set; }

        public int amount { get; set; }
        public int amount_refunded { get; set; }
        public object application { get; set; }
        public object application_fee { get; set; }
        public string balance_transaction { get; set; }
        public bool captured { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public object destination { get; set; }
        public object dispute { get; set; }
        public object failure_code { get; set; }
        public object failure_message { get; set; }
        public FraudDetails fraud_details { get; set; }
        public object invoice { get; set; }
        public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
        public object on_behalf_of { get; set; }
        public object order { get; set; }
        public object outcome { get; set; }
        public bool paid { get; set; }
        public object payment_intent { get; set; }
        public object receipt_email { get; set; }
        public object receipt_number { get; set; }
        public bool refunded { get; set; }
        public Refunds refunds { get; set; }
        public object review { get; set; }
        public object shipping { get; set; }
        public Source source { get; set; }
        public object source_transfer { get; set; }
        public object statement_descriptor { get; set; }
        public object transfer_group { get; set; }

    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Object @object { get; set; }
        public PreviousAttributes previous_attributes { get; set; }
    }

    public class FraudDetails
    {
    }


    public class Refunds
    {
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public List<object> data { get; set; }
        public bool has_more { get; set; }
        public int total_count { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Metadata2
    {
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public object address_city { get; set; }
        public object address_country { get; set; }
        public object address_line1 { get; set; }
        public object address_line1_check { get; set; }
        public object address_line2 { get; set; }
        public object address_state { get; set; }
        public object address_zip { get; set; }
        public object address_zip_check { get; set; }
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string customer { get; set; }
        public string cvc_check { get; set; }
        public object dynamic_last4 { get; set; }
        public int exp_month { get; set; }
        public int exp_year { get; set; }
        public string fingerprint { get; set; }
        public string funding { get; set; }
        public string last4 { get; set; }
        public Metadata2 metadata { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object tokenization_method { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing your json and class objects for json.

You json contains property with name `"trial_period_days": null,` has been null and you declare its respective property of type integer `public int trial_period_days { get; set; }` in `Plan` class object.

So `int` is a value type and cannot be cast to `null`.

To get rid from this exception you need to modify your property to either of below.

```
public object trial_period_days { get; set; }
```

OR

```
public int? trial_period_days { get; set; }
```

And same for your remaining properties inside `Object` class for `trial_start` and `trial_end`.

**Note:** Don't use `Object` as your custom class name because it already predefined class in .net framework.

Comment: glad to hear, please mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and up vote also :)

Comment: green it is :).

Answer (score 0):

Because there are some properties are null in your JSON data but you use value type to carry it.

You can try to use `string` type to represent your null value properties for those models to carry your JSON data.

```
  public class Metadata
{
}

public class Metadata2
{
}

public class Plan
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string @string { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string aggregate_usage { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public string billing_scheme { get; set; }
    public int created { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string interval { get; set; }
    public int interval_count { get; set; }
    public bool livemode { get; set; }
    public Metadata2 metadata { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public string tiers { get; set; }
    public string tiers_mode { get; set; }
    public string transform_usage { get; set; }
    public string trial_period_days { get; set; }
    public string usage_type { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string @string { get; set; }
    public int created { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public Plan plan { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string subscription { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
    public string @string { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public bool has_more { get; set; }
    public int total_count { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Metadata3
{
}

public class Metadata4
{
}

public class Plan2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string @string { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string aggregate_usage { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public string billing_scheme { get; set; }
    public int created { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string interval { get; set; }
    public int interval_count { get; set; }
    public bool livemode { get; set; }
    public Metadata4 metadata { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    public string product { get; set; }
    public string tiers { get; set; }
    public string tiers_mode { get; set; }
    public string transform_usage { get; set; }
    public string trial_period_days { get; set; }
    public string usage_type { get; set; }
}

public class content
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string @string { get; set; }
    public string application_fee_percent { get; set; }
    public string billing { get; set; }
    public int billing_cycle_anchor { get; set; }
    public bool cancel_at_period_end { get; set; }
    public string canceled_at { get; set; }
    public int created { get; set; }
    public int current_period_end { get; set; }
    public int current_period_start { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
    public string days_until_due { get; set; }
    public string default_source { get; set; }
    public string discount { get; set; }
    public string ended_at { get; set; }
    public Items items { get; set; }
    public bool livemode { get; set; }
    public Metadata3 metadata { get; set; }
    public Plan2 plan { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int start { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string tax_percent { get; set; }
    public string trial_end { get; set; }
    public string trial_start { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public content @object { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string idempotency_key { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string @string { get; set; }
    public string api_version { get; set; }
    public int created { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public bool livemode { get; set; }
    public int pending_webhooks { get; set; }
    public Request request { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

use will be like this

```
var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
```

**Note**

There are two way can create model easily.

- You can use Web Essentials in Visual Studio, use Edit > Paste special > paste JSON as a class, you can easier to know the relation between Json and model.
- If you can't use Web Essentials you can instead of use http://json2csharp.com/ online JSON to Model class.

You can try to use those models to carry your JSON Format.